# Javascript date: is there any way to specify that a date at midnight should be rendered as the previous day instead of the next day?

Tags: javascript, date

`new Date('August 19, 1975 24:00')` will return "Wed Aug 20 1975 00:00:00 GMT+0100".

But I would like to keep the date instead as "Wed Aug 19 1975 24:00:00 GMT+0100" in order to keep the current day at 19. (I think both representations are valid)

Is there any way to specify this preference (other than a messy patch substracting 1 day when time is 00:00)?

Comment: Any reason to specify the time specifically to 24:00?

Comment: There is nothing like 24:00 so it is not valid

Comment: And your date is 19th at 23:00:00 in my timezone

Comment: you can subtract one second from the current to accomplish this.

Comment: But the day _does_ start at midnight

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff The OP asks for the time to be _rendered_ as 24:00:00. This has uses. For example, where I live, a supermarket might have opening hours posted as 07:00-25:00, as 07:00-01:00 might seem confusing and counterintuitive ("why does it close before it opens?"). This convention is quite common here. While a JavaScript `Date` might not be able to have `24` in its `hours` field, there is nothing "not valid" about representing it so in display.

Comment: OP, there is no such flag; you have to format your date manually if you want such a representation. A trivial way to do so would be to format the date as if it was one day earlier, convert to string, then replace the hours with (hours - 24) using a regular expression.

Comment: No clock in the world ever displays `24:00`. After `23:59` it resets at `00:00`.

Comment: @JeremyThille—because you've checked **every clock in the world**? Military units may use either 2400 or 0000, though rarely use either as they are confusing and will typically set events for 2355 or 0005 to ensure the context of the start or end of the day is explicit. :-)

Comment: Ah my bad, I admit I'm not military

Comment: @Amadan has uses doesn’t mean it is valid. Using something doesn’t make it a standard which is defined in any official document. So yes, 24:00 might be used but it’s still not valid

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. A long answer is below.

> `new Date('August 19, 1975 24:00')` will return "Wed Aug 20 1975 00:00:00 GMT+0100".

Not necessarily. The string isn't in a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. Safari returns an invalid date.

You can get 24:00:00 instead of 00:00:00 using [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) (or [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)) by setting the hour cycle to h24, however it represents the start of the day, not the end. E.g.

```
new Date(2020,7,1).toLocaleString('en-CA-u-hc-h24')
```

produces "2020-08-01, 24:00:00" in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and Opera, not "2020-07-31, 24:00:00".

If both `hc-h24` and `hour12: false` are specified, it seems the *hour12* value sets the hour cycle to h23 (for en-CA at least) in Safari, Firefox and Chrome but not Opera, which keeps h24. I guess that can be put down to the implementation dependent behaviour of *Intl.DateTimeFormat* and *toLocaleString*.

```js
let d = new Date(2020,7,1,24);

console.log(
  'Default hour cycle: '   + d.toLocaleString('en-CA') +
  '\nhour12 false      : ' + d.toLocaleString('en-CA',{hour12: false}) +
  '\nh24 hour cycle    : ' + d.toLocaleString('en-CA-u-hc-h24') +
  '\nh24 + hour12 false: ' + d.toLocaleString('en-CA-u-hc-h24',{hour12: false})
);
```